# clarification about signed url and object upload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm a little confused as how to create a signed url so that a user can upload a file or a set of files to g-c-s.
I have successfully created a signed url to access a private object but now I would like to try the same for a multipart upload. It seems that POST request can't be signed so I tried a PUT request but it didn't work. I'm not sure if I have to use a different endpoint. 
Also is it possible to create a signed url without specifying the object name in advance ?
btw I'm using postman to test the upload process and go to sign the url.

Comment: Why do you want to use a signed URL with multipart?

Comment: I'm trying to upload a file without having to use a google account so that's why I'm experimenting with signed urls. the multipart is because it supports meta data. I guess it doesn't make a big difference I can settle for simple or resumable for bigger files.

Comment: Yeah, I'd go with the resumable protocol. You can create the initial POST server-side, then pass back the Upload ID to the client. The client then issues the PUTs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resumable uploads[1] instead of multipart uploads and it should work for you.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable